# Check if input field value has changed on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to check if a value has changed on an input field before submitting a form. This is the code I have so far:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitButton').click(function() {

        if( $('input[name="inputToBeChecked"]').val() != 'Original input field value' {
            alert("Input field has changed!");
        } else {
            alert("Input field has not changed!");
        }

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>

  <input type="text" name="inputToBeChecked" id="inputToBeChecked" value="Original input field value">
  <a id="submitButton" type="button" class="btn" href="javascript:void(0);">Submit form</a>

</form>
```

Comment: And the problem you're having with it is...? Other than the missing `)` if your `if/else`

Comment: You code works fine if you include the missing `)` on your if statement

Comment: Or use a placeholder attribute for default text.

Comment: the logic is fine, where to keep the original value is another matter.. I would use a `data-*` attribute to avoid having variables for each input you're interested to do this with.. but if you fix your typo the basics are ok :)

Comment: IMO this shouldn't be downvoted or closed.. even if it's pretty simple, it's someone trying to learn and we shouldn't "punish" that.. and it started some interesting questions on the side in the comments and answer.. so +1 from me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a flag once the input has been changed

```
var flag = 0;
$('input[name="inputToBeChecked"]').change(function(){
   flag = 1;
});
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
   if(flag == 1){
     //yeah!
   }
});
```

There can be also another case, if it gets changed and then returns to initial state. Then you could just save the initial value instead.

```
var initialVal;
$(document).ready(function(){
   initialVal = $('input[name="inputToBeChecked"]').val();
});
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
   if($('input[name="inputToBeChecked"]').val() != initialVal){
      // initial value changed
   } else {
      // initial value either unchanged or changed and later reversed to initial state 
   }
});
```

Comment: But the code works fine if they fix the missing `)` typo

Comment: @j08691 Nope, OP shown just an example, what if there's another value in the textfield initially, what do you speak of?

Comment: you could argue that it works even better if it's not considered changed if it's edited back to the original value.. :)

Comment: @nicael yup. I'm going strictly by what the OP posted -- not every potential possibility